# Inserting default text to the 'link' plugin in TinyMCE4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to modify the link plugin of TinyMCE so that it will display "http://" by default in the URL field. I've modified the plugin file to include a value, and that value does seem to be rendered out to the HTML

(Note: I also changed the type from "filepicker" to "textbox")

code:

```
{name:"href",type:"textbox",value:"http://",size:40,autofocus:!0,label:"Url",onchange:o,onkeyup:o}
```

resulting HTML:

```
<input id="mce_64" class="mce-textbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" value="http://" hidefocus="true" size="40" style="left: 121px; top: 0px; width: 271px; height: 26px;">
```

(Note the "value" property present in the HTML)

However, this still renders as an empty textbox for some reason. This is easily reproduced by downloading the current version of TinyMCE 4, and modifying the link plugin as I have done.

Anyone know why this is happening? Or how to just set a default value on the field?

## UPDATE

Because of this and several other issues I moved to CKEditor instead. I no longer need an answer to this, though if anyone does have an answer I'm sure it'll still be relevant to someone out there

Answer (score 0):

plugin.js, line 626 (inside 'showDialog' function):

```
data.href = anchorElm ? dom.getAttrib(anchorElm, 'href') : 'http://www.desirable_URL/';
```